# Recursive calling of method by child function

Tags: javascript

There is a class `test` which has method `addRecursively()` which has child function (is this the correct term btw?) `childFunc()` which in turn calls `addRecursively()`

```
class Test {

     addRecursively = function (i) {
        i++;
        childFunc();

        function childFunc(){
            if (i==5) {
                console.log(i);
            } else {
                console.log("Not yet");
                this.addRecursively(i); // Cannot read property 'addRecursively' of undefined
            }
        }
    }
}

var testObj = new Test();
testObj.addRecursively(0);
```

How do I call the parent function without explicily addressing `testObj` exemplar?

Comment: Make `childFunc` an arrow function.

Comment: what should happen if you call the function? `i` never change inside.

Comment: you could just exclude your function from the object
`<script> function dosomething(){
 alert("Hello");
}

dosomething();</script>`

Comment: What is this program trying to accomplish? `this` is not bound to the nested function, so it's undefined.

Comment: Actually the nested function is a normal function and it doesn't use the lexical `this` means the `this` inside the `childFunc` is not same as `this` in `addRecursively`.If you want to use `this` of parent inside nested function then use Arrow Function. Here https://jsfiddle.net/maheerali121/typ7g6m9/1/ I have created a fiddle that works fine.

Comment: @ggorlen  It's supposed to `i++` until `i==5` and `then console.log(i);` Just a simple demonstration of the problem.

Comment: You can also do this instead of arrow function: `childFunc.bind(this)`;